# Is there a way to print a selection of words in a list of strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble finding a way to be able to print only the objects in this list of strings (cars, umbrellas, cars, beaches, notebooks).

Also, is there a way to print unique elements from a list of strings (cars, umbrellas, beaches, notebooks)?

```
list = [
'cars, 1010, 1420',
'umbrellas, 1700, 1820',
'cars, 4010, 1220',
'beaches, 1800, 1120',
'notebooks, 0610, 0420']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split`:

```
elements = [
'cars, 1010, 1420',
'umbrellas, 1700, 1820',
'cars, 4010, 1220',
'beaches, 1800, 1120',
'notebooks, 0610, 0420']

print([string.split(',')[0] for string in elements])
# ['cars', 'umbrellas', 'cars', 'beaches', 'notebooks']
```

If you want unique names, simply use a set compression instead of the list comprehension:

```
print({string.split(',')[0] for string in elements})
# {'cars', 'notebooks', 'umbrellas', 'beaches'}
```

Or with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
print(set(map(lambda string: string.split(',')[0], elements)))
# {'notebooks', 'umbrellas', 'cars', 'beaches'}
```